# Ignore initial reducer values and only render once

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When we define our reducers we give them initial values. The problem is that more often than not it is not our intention as programmers to do these two renders: first the initial values (not real) and then second the real final values. Is there a strategy to ignore initial values while rendering and only do **one render** with the final values of the reducer?

Comment: If you can guess the final values correctly then you only need to render once...

Comment: I think a good pattern for this if the initial value is never intended to be rendered is to actually set it to some value that isn't a valid output value and check if the state value isn't that value. For example, I may set an initial value to `null` and check if it still equals null and render a loading indicator, or if it is still `null` simply return `null` from the render function of the component you don't want to display bad data.

Comment: @DrewReese That's exactly what I was thinking. I picked an arbitrary string property and set the initial value of it to "loading." Ideally no matter what I get from my API (whether 0 elements or 20) this property will be over written every single time once the reducer finishes.